# how to pass multiple commands to sqlite3 in a one liner shell command

Tags: bash, shell-script, sqlite, bash-expansion

I'm trying to save clipboard content into an sqlite database. Created database and tables.

I don't want it to create `journal` file in every clipboard  change, so I tried to pass `PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;` flag. But it's tricky to pass those commands in a one liner commands because `sqlite` only accepts two command like

```
sqlite3 clipboard_archive.db "insert into cb (cb_context) values ('clipboard');"
```

it works. 
I looked for `Q&A` sites, some advises echoing the commands in the following way.

```
echo "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;" | sqlite3 clipboard_archive.db "insert into cb (cb_context) values ('clipboard');"
```

But `PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;` doesn't take effect in that way though it works within the `sqlite3` command prompt.

What's wrong with my one liner script?

Comment: You should either put all of the commands in through `echo` or all of them as an argument to `sqlite3`.

Comment: @chicks "I believe I tried that but it didn't work in my attempt." you know it's a `noob phenomenon`. If you posted it as an answer, I'd have another option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use SQLite if you don't want the journal (have you considered the much faster WAL mode if speed is a concern?) but you can give multiple commands separated by semicolons:

```
sqlite3 clipboard_archive.db "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF; insert into cb (cb_context) values ('clipboard');"
```

Comment: I just had time to test it, it works, thanks. I am just a beginner in data storing. Thank you for the suggestion, I was not aware of `WAL` mode. I ll take a look at it. My concern was not speed, I didn't want hard disk to wear down.

Answer (score 16):

[derobert](/users/977/derobert)'s answer doesn't seem to work with dot-commands, but you can use `-cmd`: `sqlite3 tolls.sql3 -cmd ".mode csv" ".import tolls.csv tolls"`

it accepts multiple `-cmd` commands and executes them in order, before the final arg.

Comment: On CentOS 7 when I try to use more than one command with the -cmd argument I get an Error: too many options.
However, what does work is the following:
`sqlite3 some.db -cmd ".separator ','" <<< ".import table1.csv table1" <<< ".import table2.csv table2"`

Comment: on Windows, if you install sqlite3 you can pass dot commands without the -cmd argument, i.e.: `sqlite3 some.db ".separator ','" ".import table1.csv table1" ".import table2.csv table2"`
I know this is unrelated to UNIX, but I wanted to include this comment just in case people find this article online and they are on Windows.

Comment: I wonder if there is any nicer way to make it not stop to read from stdin after doing that than `echo | sqlite3 ...`. Tried `-cmd '.quit'` but didn't work, sqlite3 3.33.

Answer (score 6):

You can run…

```sql
$ sqlite3 <database_file> '<statement_1>' ['<statement_n>']
```

#### Example…

```sql
$ sqlite3 data.db '.mode json' 'select * from my_table'
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you can use the `-cmd` switch not only once. This also works for me (SQLite 3.8.7.2 on Windows):

`sqlite3.exe yourdb.db -cmd ".mode column" -cmd ".headers on" "select * from persons;"`